# Where with OneToMany relation in TypeORM

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript, typeorm

How to create a function in [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io) to find an data by time range in `OneToMany` entity?

I create an `where` clause to find:

```
        const users = await this.conn
            .getRepository(User)
            .find({
                select: ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'sex', 'birthdate', 'subAddress', 'address', 'city', 'district', 'disabilityType'],
                join: {
                    alias: "user",
                    leftJoinAndSelect: {
                        order: "user.orders"
                    }
                },
                where: {
                    order.createdAt: Between(dto.from, dto.to)//HERE
                }
            });
```

but it not work and always throw me `NOT_FOUND` :/

can someone show how this should be?

Comment: Did you get your answer? I am looking for exactly the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the results based on filter for the child record and I am not sure if it works with typeorm(based on my experience with other language).
However I found some articles on GitHub which may help you.

An alternative solution link:
[here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3890#issuecomment-578762035)

Bug reported and in status open:[here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4280)

I hope it guides you somehow